# Building an Expression using Expression.NotEqual method on a nullable property

Tags: c#, expression

I am building queries using an Expression builder. However, each time I am adding the following Expression I am getting an error:

```
Expression.NotEqual("TableProperty", constant)
```

The error:
"the character set is not recognized as a valid Datetime. The index 0 starts with an unknown word".

When I running a similar query which is the same, except I use Expression.Equals, it does not return this error.

Further inspecting the error tells me the problem occurs at DateTime.Parse(). So it seems that the current structure of the querybuilder does not suffice for this operator on a nullable type.

Does anyone know a good solution to this problem?

Comment: A datetime object does not have a null option.  The default is 1/1/01.  So for null you can test for 1/1/01 or just test for anything > 1900.

Comment: We need a full example here... Unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

I fiddled a bit and got it working like this (I assumethis makes clear what I was asking as well)

```
 if (member.Type.IsGenericType && member.Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
 {
       var isNullCheck = Expression.Equal(member, Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(null), member.Type));
       return Expression.Or(isNullCheck, Expression.NotEqual(Expression.Property(member, "HasValue"), constant));
 }
 return Expression.NotEqual(Expression.Property(member, "HasValue"), constant);
```

The member variable here refers to the "TableProperty"